# Will it be possible to update Windows XP after April 2014?

Tags: windows-xp

Sometimes I want to test something on Windows XP for development purposes and I am curious if I will be able to make new fresh XP installation after end of support in April 2014.

OK, no new updates will be published by Microsoft after April 2014. But what happens if I install Windows XP SP3 after April 2014 and then will want to update it to latest existing updates? Will it be possible or not? With Windows Update, or some kind of "rollup" package?

(Many people already asked if they will be able to install the XP after April 2014. But I can't see any questions about updates.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly before april 2014 make a clean install, update it and make an image backup.
(Make several copies and test them :-) )
Use this image to restore to your new test systems.

Perhaps install XP in a virtual machine under e.g. windows 8 pro or vmware. Then have backup of the virtual machine to use when creating test machines.

Comment: OK, this actually doesn't answer my question, but it's a usable workaround. So I am going to accept this answer.

Answer (score 5):

Actual answer now that it's only a few days away:

"Will existing updates still be available via Windows Update after April 8, 2014?"

> Yes, all existing Windows XP updates and fixes will still be available via Windows Update and WSUS.

Source: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/end-of-support.aspx

Comment: Confirmed. I just did a XP reinstall in September 2014. I had SP2 and SP3 on CD and installed those from there, but all the other 'old' patches came in through Windows update. There is a chicken and egg issue along the route: XP comes with IE6 and you can't access Windows update from it. But updates will start automatically and download IE8 and then that's solved too.

Answer (score -1):

It is likely that Microsoft will take down all the updates, and will simply redirect to a page instructing you to upgrade windows. I would reccomend that you grab a copy of WSUS Offline (http://www.wsusoffline.net/) and tell it to download all windows XP updates.

Comment: I doubt that, I still see things for Windows 2000 or NT tucked away in their KB pages, but nonetheless it is an impending danger.